# Generate jar with Bundle-SymbolicName value in a Liferay module

Tags: gradle, liferay-7, bnd

By default, Blade generates the jar file of a module including the module version.

Searching information about how to remove the version from de filename, I was success change the jar's name with only the project name using this code in the workspace **build.gradle** file:

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    jar.archiveFileName = "${project.name}.jar"
}
```

Now, I'm trying to use the symbolic name of the module (the value from the **Bundle-SymbolicName** attribute in **bnd.bnd** file) to generate the jar, but I can't find the way to get it from the **build.gradle** file.

Is there way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the solution was quite simple. When using the `deploy` task from the Liferay plugin in IntelliJ, it generates the `.jar` file with the version in the `build/libs` directory of the module, but deploys it to the server (directory `bundles/osgi/modules`) without the version.